# select columns from a called procedure sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to call a procedure from a `Linked Server`.

The call is this :
`EXEC ('CALL DBA.procedure (?)', @Date) at SERVER`

The procedure returns some columns, but i want to change their name and to order them by some columns.

I tried to declare a variable and then to execute it like this :

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000);
      SET @SQL = 
      ' Select date Date,
        location LocationCurrent,
        nr_people NumberOfPeople,
        money Monetizing
        from '' EXEC (''CALL DBA.procedure (?)'', @Date) at SERVER''
        ORDER BY Date, NumberOfPeople '    

         EXEC Sp_executesql 
        @SQL
```

But like this won't work. I don't know the syntax , but i am sure you can help me !!!

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax like `FROM ... EXEC..`

You need first to store result in table like:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(...);

INSERT INTO #tab(...)
EXEC ('CALL DBA.procedure(''2015-09-09'')' ) AT SERVER;

SELECT 
   date Date,
   location LocationCurrent,
   nr_people NumberOfPeople,
   money Monetizing
FROM #tab
ORDER BY Date, NumberOfPeople;
```

Or use `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT 
  date Date,
  location LocationCurrent,
  nr_people NumberOfPeople,
  money Monetizing
FROM OPENQUERY(SERVER, 'CALL DBA.procedure(''2015-09-09'')')
ORDER BY date, nr_people;
```

Comment: in the parantheses what should i write? instead of "..."

Comment: @xyz Your table definition like `date DATETIME, location NVARCHAR(100), ...` Only you know what types stored procedure returns

Comment: it gives me this error `The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSERVER" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.`

Comment: You need to enable distributed transaction then http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60858/how-can-i-enable-distributed-transactions-for-a-linked-server

Comment: if i try with open query `An error occurred while preparing the query "CALL DBA.procedure(?), @Date" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSERVER". `

Comment: first i tried this `SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(server, 'CALL DBA.procedure(''2015-09-09'')')`

Comment: `Cannot execute the query "CALL DBA.procedure('2015-09-09')" against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "myserver". `

Comment: @xyz Do you enabled `Remote RPC` in your linked server?

Comment: i am using odbc, my conection with server is with sql anywhere

Comment: @xyz Try `SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(SERVER, 'CALL DBA.procedure(''''2015-09-09'''')')`

Comment: `An error occurred while preparing the query "CALL DBA.procedure(''2015-09-09'')" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server". `

Comment: but this is how i use the stament for calling the procedure : `CALL DBA.procedure (?)', @param`

Comment: i tried this but the same problem : `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(server, ' ''CALL DBA.procedure(?)'', @param')     `

Comment: i did it finally :) thank you very much, it wasn't something wrong with the code,i have set `Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions` to `false` from my `linked server properties`